# Spring Batch using Spring Boot and Maven Modules

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, module, spring-batch

While working on a Spring Batch project, I'd like to create modules for each of the necessary batch functions. For example, the following shows the  tag in the pom.xml file:

```
<modules>
   <module>db_common</module>
   <module>sor_one</module>
   <module>sor_two</module>
<modules>
```

where the db_common module will have the common database configuration for creating DataSouce that is shared by all modules. The sor_one module will have the jar for the @Configuration and classes for SOR #1, and the sor_two module will have the jar for the @Configuration and associated classes for SOR #2.

When I am ready to run this, I will run two applications. One for sor_one, and the other for sor_two by putting the corresponding jar file on the CLASSPATH for each of the apps.

I noticed there are some discussions of using spring-boot-maven-plugin. Including this plugin seems to complain about I don't have the main function in the sor_one and sor_two projects.

Please guide me as I must be missing something about the plugin and now I like to organize my applications. Thank you so much!

Sincerely,

Student_t

Comment: spring boot is evil.

Comment: Sounds like you know what to do with this to achieve my goals?